# How to fetch data from AWS RDS in AWS Glue job script and transform the data accordingly and insert it back in aws rds?

Tags: amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I want to insert data from s3 bucket csv through AWS Glue but insertion of data depends on the data stored in AWS RDS(like if that data already present in then do not insert or if already present and only some attributes of that data is updated then update the values ). Is there any way to fetch the data from RDS in AWS Glue job script and then transform the data accordingly.

I also thought of calling AWS lambda after AWS Glue job completion.
Is there any code for aws glue job script to call lambda after aws glue job completion or any way to get the response of aws glue job like SNS or something by which we can call lambda ?

I want that after insertion of data in aws rds table, a stored procedure is called which will process data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've managed to insert data straight into a MySQL Aurora cluster from Glue jobs and avoid duplicates by simply sending INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements. It looks something like this:

```
import mysql

# Other logic here...

# Convert to DataFrame (from a DynamicFrame) 
df = mapping.toDF()

# Connect to MySQL
db = mysql.connect(glueContext, 'name-of-mysql-connection', 'db')
cursor = db.cursor()

insert_statement = """
  INSERT INTO my_table
  (column1, column2, updated_at)
  VALUES(%s, %s, NOW())
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  column1 = %s,
  column2 = %s,
  updated_at = NOW()
  """

# Execute each statement
for row in df.rdd.collect():
  cursor.execute(insert_statement, (
    row['column1'],
    row['column2'],
    row['column1'],
    row['column2']
  ))

# Commit to the database
db.commit()
db.close()
```